# The Component 'TopSearchBarComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule - Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I am new to angular. I have Component like TopSearchBarComponent. I need to use this same component in all module.
I have following modules

```
app.module.ts
a.module.ts
b.modules.ts
```

If i declare TopSearchBarComponent in both ngModule i receive the error like  **declared by more than one NgModule**

My question is how to use same component in all modules best way.

Thank you,

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components cannot be declared in more than one module, so if you are to use a component in more than one module then the simple solution would be to declare the component in it's own module and export it, Using the CLI you can run

- `ng g m my-element` This generates MyElementModule
- `ng g c my-element` This generates MyElementComponent declared in MyElementModule in step 1 above
- Lastly, in the `@NgModule` decorators array of MyElementModule add `exports` array with MyElementComponent

After this, whenever you wish to use this component you simply import the module, this way the component will never be declared in more than one module